# Eclipse hide Package Explorer and other windows when I run app

Tags: java, eclipse

I have very frustrating problem and can't deal with it.
It seems like I clicked something what unlocked my UI and it's getting crazy every time I restart Eclipse and launch app from Package Explorer.

Symptoms:
- every time I restart app whole perspective is hidden
- after running app, when I click on class perspective its hiding again

I tried to reset to defaults and deleting .metadata but it didn't help.

Cheers :)

Comment: Have you tried saving the perspective after you modify it. Windows -> Perspective -> Save Perspective As...

Comment: Yes, I tried that too.

Comment: Maybe it's the debug perspective that needs reconfiguration? Default debug perspective behaviour is to focus on code and variable values

Comment: Now I know that you are frustrated, but not what you mean by _"class perspective"_ and how something can hide again when it is already hidden (and that's frustrating, too, because it' not possible for me to answer your question). Please add a screenshot and explain how to reproduce this issue. Which Eclipse version do you have? Do you have additional plug-ins installed?